# Different values in navigation timing api and chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigation-timing-api

I'v found a sample on [google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp?hl=en) that explains how to use navigation timing api to measure dom ready time for example. The problem is that the resulting values are very different about those values that shows in the chrome developer tools. In what could be the error?

So, here we can see that DCL-event takes about 590ms and Page Complete time is about 594ms *(sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images, can you open developer tools, please)*. But... the values captured from navigation timing api are totally different *(here should be link to the google article)*.

That's how they get this values:

```
var t = window.performance.timing,
    interactive = t.domInteractive - t.domLoading;
```